# BIRT reports integration with PHP

Tags: php, tomcat, birt

I'm trying to integrate BIRT report viewer to my PHP application.

My questions are:

1. What is the client side requirement to view the report?
2. The report viewer needs tomcat and BIRT to be installed on the server machine. Which works perfectly fine on my own machine or dedicated server. But what if there is a shared hosting?
   Is there a solution to run PHP+MySQL+ BIRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) On client side actually nothing. On the server side, you have the `.rptdesign` files and your server will generate the file in desired format from it, so the client can just download and open this file in appropriate program (like Excel, Acrobat Reader and so on).

2) You need the embedded servlet container because you need to deploy [WebViewer](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerSetup.php) which can be a problem on a shared hosting. There are some workarounds for this but IMHO is not really worth to try ([source)](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/25920-can-reports-be-viewed-using-shared-hosting-providers/page__s__abff2dd82feaf43f69f8ef4217e5e40a)